# Variable inside AT+UHTTPC command

Tags: arduino, gprs

I'm trying to figure out how to include a variable that I grab from a sensor inside an AT+UHTTPC command to post the values inside a DB.

I tried using the HTTPPAR command but it seems the GPRS I have doesn't recognize it ( I have a SARA G350 GPRS shield )

Here's the code I'm using right now which cannot contain a variable :

```
 mySerial.println("AT+UHTTPC=2,5,\"/add.php\",\"post.ffs\",\"vite=10\",0"); updateSerial(); 
delay(1000);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "include a vraible"? Are you trying to change a value inside your AT command string? If yes which one do you want to change?

Comment: For example, I grab a value from a windspeed sensor, I want to send that value to the DB using the AT command

Comment: Example :
 float Windspeed = analogRead(A0);
 mySerial.println("AT+UHTTPC=2,5,\"/add.php\",\"post.ffs\",\"vite=Windspeed\",0"); 
 updateSerial(); 
 delay(1000);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to read your sensor value and create a new string based on that then pass it to your serial output.

```
void send_value()
{
    String command = "AT+UHTTPC=2,5,\"/add.php\",\"post.ffs\",\"vite=";
    float Windspeed = analogRead(A0);
    // convert value to String
    command += String(Windspeed);
    // or convert with precision
    // command += String(Windspeed, 2);
    command += "\",0";
    mySerial.println(command);
    updateSerial();
    delay(1000);
}
```